# forcing compilation Jade partials with utf8 charset in Gulp

Tags: angularjs, utf-8, character-encoding, pug, gulp

How to force Jade files to be compiled to HTML utf8 encoding?.

I am using Gulp. I have multiple templates that are included (using AngularJS) into `index.html`, so, the meta tag

```
head
  meta(content='text/html', charset='utf-8')
```

is only included in `index.jade` and here all is rendering fine, but other templates are rendering special characters like á, é, í, ó, ú with � symbol.

What I need to do for avoid this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Try to check your `*.jade` file with Notepad++, and change encoding to UTF-8 (without BOM).

Comment: As I said, `index.jade` is rendering fine into `index.html`, but I have other partials .jade files where the encoding fails.

Comment: Sorry, my eng not good enough. Do you check another files encoding?